# How to change label border color when radio is checked?

Tags: html, css

I need the label's border color to change when the radio inside is selected **without using ids**.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px
}

.selectable {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.selectable:active {
    border: 1px solid #0d6efd;
}

.selectable:hover {
    background: #20c997;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    margin: 20% auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
    background: #20c997;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
    border-color: #20c997;
}
```

```html
<label class="selectable">
    <input type="radio" name="selectable">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, impedit.</span>
</label>
<label class="selectable">
    <input type="radio" name="selectable">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, impedit.</span>
</label>
<label class="selectable">
    <input type="radio" name="selectable">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, impedit.</span>
</label>
<label class="selectable">
    <input type="radio" name="selectable">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, impedit.</span>
</label>
```

This is [how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KM19.png) a checked radio button should look like. I don't want to use an id, I want to make changes to css only if possible or keep html changes at minimum by adding classes, no ids **.

I tried many things including:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
    border-color: #20c997;
}
```

and

```
.selectable:checked {
    border-color: #20c997;
}
```

and nothing is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following selector:

```
.selectable:has(input:checked){
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: any documentation that I should refer to when encountering these issues? I'm asking because I'm always struggling with such trivial problems.

Comment: This is more of a concept and has is a fairly new selector. You can just keep diversifying where you're learning from. Kevin Powell has a great YouTube channel for css